# Node.js - restrict direct access to server? Only allow/load if coming from other page AND if form POST vars are present

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express

Couldn't find any documentation on this so:

Is there any way to restrict users from directly accessing node.js server? website.com:3000

Right now if user visits my node.js website it crashes whole server and takes it offline because the server depends on variables (user id, user email).

These variables come from website.com page, where there is login form, when user clicks Login it sends POST variables to website.com:3000 where it saves them and user is counted as logged in.

So anyway to restrict direct access? Or what is the correct way to check if variable is null, if yes then socket disconnect (disconnect client basically and show error message to him).

Comment: First off, if ANY kind of request crashes your server, that means your server is in need of some defensive coding.  It should validate all incoming requests to see if they are valid before just blindly processing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server is on the internet, it needs to be able to handle requests that come from anywhere without crashing or doing something bad.

That is the responsibility of good server coding.  It should defensively test all requests to see if they contain valid information.  If not, they can simply return quickly either an error or without doing anything.

You cannot reliably tell exactly where a request is coming from.   A request that comes from a form hosted by `website.com` is actually coming from that user's browser (not from website.com) so you can't at the connection level tell the difference between an incoming connection that you like versus one that you don't like.

As such, it sounds like the simpler way to solve this is to just test the incoming data to see if it contains all the valid data you need.  If it does not, then create an appropriate response and return that without doing any harm to your server or its data.

Comment: So if I test variables/data, how can I close clients connection/socket?

Comment: @arleitiss - That depends upon what server technology you are using.  In nodejs, you can just do `response.end("Invalid request")` (add whatever actual response you want to be sent which the request is invalid) and then return from the response handling.  Is there a reason your question is tagged with both PHP and nodejs?

Comment: The login forms are handled by PHP on standard website running on port 80. 
Node.js is my chat application where users get redirected after successful login.

Comment: Then, you will have validate the incoming form requests in the PHP code and return an error if they don't contain valid info.  I don't know PHP myself so can't advise you on how to do that.  If you posted your PHP code (perhaps in a new question) that was processing the form request, others could probably help you with that.

Comment: Well, you see the problem is:
When user logins -> PHP does Ajax request which validates user details dynamically -> IF ok = redirect to chat. 

When it redirects to chat -> Node.js grabs POST variables and saves them to users online list. 

The problem starts when user accesses chat chat.com:3000 (for example) directly, so Node.js tries to get POST vars, but fails and causes crash.

Comment: @arleitiss - so why doesn't the nodejs chat connection just check the incoming data to see if it's valid before trying to use it?

Comment: Well that's the thing, I am pretty new to using JavaScript in such big scale, and I am not sure how to validate it, like do I compare it to null, or "" or what?

Comment: @arleitiss - please post a new question with the relevenat pieces of your actual nodejs code.  When you want help with your specific code, it's nearly always advisable to post the code you have or the code you tried so people can use that as a starting point and advise you on what to add or change.

Comment: Okay thanks. Will try out few things then ask for help with code if it's further required.